# Galaxy Nexus reboots on USB connection

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus, charging, reboot

I've had my Galaxy Nexus since April of 2012, and it's been fairly reliable ever since.  However, for the past few weeks, I've noticed that it's rebooting whenever I plug it into my computer for charging.

Also, I've not flashed or rooted the phone.  Is there a way to view logs on a phone to get a better idea of why it might be crashing?  Some sort of equivalent to Windows' Event Viewer?

Any help is appreciated.

UPDATE - I've noticed that this also happens when charging via AC as well; meaning it's not just happening when I charge via USB.

Comment: That is odd. Some sort of short I'd imagine. But it doesn't do it when you charge by AC? Are you using stock, or have you flashed something custom?

Comment: @Krampus - I've added more info to address your questions.  I'll test to see if it happens when I charge on other computers.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planned_obsolescence ?